# Transforming Pyplot x axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, scipy

I am trying to plot an audio sample's amplitude across the time domain. I've used [scipy.io.wavfile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.read.html) to read the audio sample and determine sampling rate:

```
# read .wav file
data = read("/Users/user/Desktop/voice.wav")

# determine sample rate of .wav file
# print(data[0]) # 48000 samples per second
# 48000 (samples per second) * 4 (4 second sample) = 192000 samples overall

# store the data read from .wav file
audio = data[1]

# plot the data
plt.plot(audio[0 : 192000]) # see code above for how this value was determined
```

This creates a plot displaying amplitude on y axis and sample number on the x axis. How can I transform the x axis to instead show seconds?

I tried using `plt.xticks` but I don't think this is the correct use case based upon the error I received:

```
# label title, axis, show the plot
seconds = range(0,4)
plt.xticks(range(0,192000), seconds)
plt.ylabel("Amplitude")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.show()
```

```
ValueError: The number of FixedLocator locations (192000), usually from a call to set_ticks, does not match the number of ticklabels (4).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a *t* vector to the plotting command, a vector that you can generate on the fly using Numpy, so that after the command execution it is garbage collected (sooner or later, that is)

```
from numpy import linspace
plt.plot(linspace(0, 4, 192000, endpoint=False), audio[0 : 192000])
```